# Garbage Collector vs Pool

Tags: java, android, memory-management, garbage-collection, tree

I'm running simulations that involve the creation of a tree.
My tree has a branching factor from 2/3 to 7/8.

Each time i need to expand it i allocate an array for the child.
Quite often i make a single branch the new tree(by setting a child of the root as the root), so the rest of my tree become garbage.

I'm wondering if it is better to let the garbage collector do his work (i "suggest" him to start collecting with System.gc() when i change the tree root) or implement my own pool for TreeNodes, and when i change the root, recycle all the now useless nodes.

The answer can be read as: is the android garbage collector very optimized or is it preferable to limiting the creation/destruction of object, even if this is quite consuming?(i would need to traverse all the tree, and append each useless node to a stack for my pool)

I read that android GC is not as "evolved"(it basically runs when you have low memory.) In addition i don't know if just deleting every reference to the root of the tree will let the gc garbage collect all the tree in a single pass, or it will gc only the node, then the children of that node the next pass, and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you need to understand if GC is even a worry for you. So run your app with -verbosegc. If your GC reports performance issues or a memory build up you can worry about it. Else eliminate it from your equation of things to do.

The GC works on generations. Basically your allocations are separated into generations. As your app loads all allocations fall under generation 0. And as the app progresses your allocations are put into Generation 1 and 2. The GC when it runs does not work very often on Generation 0 as it would on 1. Similarly it would not run more often on generation 1 as it would on 2. This is done with the assumption that objects that you allocate at load time dont need to be freed as often as objects created later on.

Interesting quote from http://chaoticjava.com/posts/how-does-garbage-collection-work/

- In any application, objects could be categorized according to their
  life-line.
- Some objects are short-lived, such as most local
  variables, and some are long-lived such as the backbone of the
  application.
- The thought about generational garbage collection was
  made possible with the understanding that in an applicationâ€™s
  lifetime, most instantiated objects are short-lived, and that there
  are few connections between long-lived objects to short-lived
  objects.

Comment: I already read that article(and yes, it is really interesting), but i'm talking specifically about android gc. In my application it seams to run often (the logcat prints GC_Concurrent, free x% y/z, taken 5ms + 6ms). On my application is not a performance issue (it still runs 60fps), i'm most wondering about best practices **for android(so mobile)** platforms (the article is from 2008, so i don't think it can apply on android gc, in addition i think android gc changed a lot in later versions)

Comment: Implementing your own treenodes is actually a interesting way to solve it. The question is what are you measuring here. If you are not measuring performance, then memory utilization ? Unless you know what you are measuring here, you dont know what benefits either can give you. Is GC taking up too much time, aren't you getting the response you expect from you app ? Is it taking up too much memory ? Do you think by writing your own pool, you will improve the gc? If gc is your issue, then you should measure how much time gc is using up,and then write your pool,and measure again.Are you measuring?

Comment: I already have a generic pool, so writing a pool for my TreeNode is a matter of updating to correct values when requesting a TreeNode and traversing the tree to recycle all the children when recycling a TreeNode. Memory doesn't seams to be a problem for now (i didn't tried yet long time simulations, since i still have some bug to solve in my code), and cpu isn't too, but since i'm running on mobile, the more efficient my code is the less battery i'll make the user waste, and android is cruel on this subject(it clearly show how much battery an app consumes). No, i'm not measuring.. (good point)

Comment: To measure, its important that you compare with something fixed. For example, your allocation samples across all hardware. I suggest that you measure on a 2 CPU, 2Gb desktop, and your mobile device's too. This will give you a "max" that u just cannot cross. You should also run the same tests on a 1 CPU, 1Gb desktop. Keep the jdk version 1.6 across all tests and hardware. I know what you are thinking now, will measuring a desktop be relevant. It will be, it will give you the "max"'s of response times, time taken to traverse the tree.